# ¿Para que sirve la propiedad XML fitSystemWindows (android)?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = true
```

En diversas ocasiones me he topado con esta propiedad para la elaboración de layouts, sin embargo en muchas ocasiones esta misma ocasioná comportamientos no esperados, que llevan tiempo identificar que esto lo ocasioná.

Definición obtenida del sitio oficial:

> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar.

Lo que comprendo es que esta propiedad hace que mi layout abarque toda la pantalla, pero lo he visto implementado en diversos lugares y no veo exactamente que función desempeña o si se puede prescindir de esta.

Comment: Con este atributo o propiedad, conseguimos que el Drawer o Cajón no oculte la barra de estado '*hará que esa parte quede translúcida o transparente*'.
A partir de la **API 21** '*Android 5.0*' o superior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por medio del atributo `fitsSystemWindows`, conseguimos que el `<NavigationDrawer>` o Cajón no oculte la barra de estado y se vea por debajo de la barra de estado del sistema '*hará que esa parte quede translúcida o transparente*'.
A partir de la **API 21** '*Android 5.0*' o superior.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para entender un poco más sobre esta propiedad, imagina que tienes un status bar (barra de estado) y abajo un listado, al agregar un `ListView` puede ser que el primer elemento no sea visible, ya que la status bar se muestra arriba del ListView, para evitar este problema ea precisamente mediante 
la propiedad

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = true
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las ventanas del sistema son las partes de la pantalla donde el sistema dibuja contenido no interactivo ( barra de estado).

La mayoría de las ocasiones, nuestra aplicación no necesitará dibujar debajo de la barra de estado o la barra de navegación, pero si lo hace, se debe asegurar que los elementos no estén ocultos debajo. Eso es lo que le ofrece el comportamiento predeterminado del atributo android:

`android:fitsSystemWindows = "true`"

establece un padding (relleno) de la vista para garantizar que los elementos contenidos no se superpongan a las ventanas del sistema.

Comment: El voto negativo no es mio.

En respuesta al comentario:
Entonces ¿tiene la misma función que la propiedad:  
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` ? 
tomando en cuenta tu ejemplo, esta se le colocaría al listView. de ser así sigo en las mismas: ¿Se puede prescindir de "fitsSystemWindows"?